# java batch program terminates after executing Jobbuilder.build()

Tags: java, spring-batch, listener

I am working on spring batch application wherein it loads all configuration for all batch pgms in Config class. After executing all config class methods it terminates on jobbuilder.build() method ,Please find BELOW the console output for reference.
The process() method is not called thereafter.
Please guide.

```
2021-12-09 01:52:50 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  142 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.datareportReader() : Building  the Step  ..
2021-12-09 01:53:19 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  164 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.job() : Building the Batch job ...
2021-12-09 01:54:35 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  188 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.wppdatareportReader() : Building  the Step  ..
2021-12-09 01:54:47 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  323 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.cancdatareportReader() : Building  the Step  ..{}
2021-12-09 01:54:58 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  210 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.weeklyPPJob() : Building the Batch WeeklyPPJob ...
2021-12-09 01:55:47 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  231 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.ppJob() : Building the Batch PlanProvisionJob ...
2021-12-09 01:55:52 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  362 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.ackStep() : Building  the Step  ..
2021-12-09 01:55:52 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  290 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.aedatareportReader() : Building  the Step  ..
2021-12-09 01:55:53 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  263 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.aeFleetJob() : Building the Batch AutoEnrollmentJob ...
2021-12-09 01:55:55 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  351 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.ackJob() : Building the Batch PlanProvisionAckJob ...
2021-12-09 01:55:58 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  277 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.aeCoinJob() : Building the Batch AutoEnrollmentJob ...
2021-12-09 01:56:02 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  310 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.cancJob() : Building the Batch CancJob ...{}
2021-12-09 01:56:06 DEBUG WeeklyPlanProvisionJob  249 com.fca.mvp.batch.main.BatchConfiguration.aeCpovJob() : Building the Batch AutoEnrollmentJob ...
```

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot? If yes, it should be sufficient to expose the jobs as beans. If not, you'll need to launch them yourself with the `JobLauncher`.

Comment: I am not using spring boot , its a plain spring application

Comment: It's not sufficient to build the jobs. You also need to start them with the `JobLauncher` or the `CommandLineJobRunner`. Please have a look here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#runningAJob